# "Decorated with taste" or "tastefully decorated"

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence should be used when referring to good quality?

> The house is decorated with taste.
>
> The house is tastefully decorated.

Is there any difference?

Comment: The first one seems awkward to me, and I prefer the second. An alternative to the first: "The person who decorated the house shows good taste". Combining the passive voice with "taste" seems peculiar.

Comment: Are you wanting to describe the quality of the decorating, or the quality of the decorations? To me, the use of passive voice stresses that someone did the decorating, while the second sentence is just describing the house.

Comment: I would like to stress the quality of the decorating.

Answer (score 1):

In essence the first one is more preferable, but I believe the second one is not wrong and you can use it when using adverb with the *decorate*; for example:

> beautifully decorated with taste

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the second as well, although it is somewhat overused these days.  Who knows what one's taste is as opposed to the next anyway, express it better, get your point across.

Answer (score 0):

I find the first sentence awkward. The fact that I had to pause, replay the sentence, to figure out the meaning. It feels as though *with taste* is an afterthought. Mind you, it does convey the same meaning as the second sentence.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taste

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tasteful

Just keep thinking about those sentences written in Q&A form.

*Question* How was the house decorated?

*Answer* With taste

*Answer* Tastefully

Answer (score 0):

tastefully is an adjective and in the second sense modifies the understanding of how the house has been decorated.

Meanwhile, the first could be taken to mean that the walls have, you know, flavor.

Comment: You mean 'tastefully' is an adverb, right?

Answer (score -1):

"The house is decorated with taste" vs. "The house is tastefully decorated."

How tastefully do you wish to decorate your verbiage? These phrases are identical. Choose the one that resonates with you; there is no right or wrong answer here.